# Binding RichTextBox text to ListBox Selected Item in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a view which contains a `ListBox` and a `RichTextBox`. My `ListBox` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` and works great:

```
 <ListBox Name="checkListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ModelviewArticleObservableList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="ArticleHeader" />
```

I now want to bind my `RichTextBox` text to the `SelectedItem` of my `ListBox`, displaying a different column from the `ObservableCollection` (ArticleBody).

Here's my exposed string property in my `ViewModel`:

```
    private string _SelectedArticle;
    public string SelectedArticle
    {
        get { return _SelectedArticle; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedArticle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedArticle");
        }
    }
```

& here's my current `RichTextBox Xaml`:

```
 <xctk:RichTextBox Name="richTextBox1" Text="{Binding SelectedArticle, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Now, the selected item is fired on `ListBox` selection but my `RichTextBox text` is obviously displaying the class name rather than the ArticleBody text which I want.

How do I get my `SelectedArticle` string property to return the ArticleBody as opposed to the class name?

Comment: Write a IValueConverter that returns the text you want instead of class name.

Comment: @Hardgraf, what is the type of `ModelviewArticleObservableList`? Is it `ObservableList<ModelviewArticle>` or `ObservableList<string>`?

Comment: @dkozl it is an ObservableCollection<viewArticle> ViewArticle is my model class with exposed properties including 'ArticleBody'. I understand that my SelectedArticle string property can't understand the ViewArticle object it's being passed but not sure how to deal with this issue... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ModelviewArticleObservableList` is `ObservableCollection<viewArticle>` change `SelectedArticle` to be of a `viewArticle` type (same as your collection item type)

```
private viewArticle _SelectedArticle;

public viewArticle SelectedArticle
{
    get { return _SelectedArticle; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedArticle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedArticle");
    }
}
```

and then change `RichTextBox` binding to use `SelectedArticle.ArticleBody` path

```
<xctk:RichTextBox Name="richTextBox1" Text="{Binding SelectedArticle.ArticleBody, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: fantastic thankyou! All makes sense now, just expose a property of the type you are passing to. Thanks for all your help, Tom

Comment: No problem @Hardgraf. Glad it helps. If you use bindings then `SelectedItem(s)` will be of collection item type.